# Store R loop result and combine it with new result

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R loop and sorry if this question is too simple. I'm trying to write a loop to subset data. The codes are:

```
a <- sample(rep(1:5, 10), 10)
b <- sample(rep(1:5, 10), 10)
c <- data.frame(a, b)
s <- c(1,2)
for (i in s){
  x <- data.frame()
  x <- rbind(x, c[which(a==i),])
}
```

The x only includes the result for a=2. But when I deleted x and used print() command, it gave me a data frame under the conditions of a=1 and a=2. I don't know what's wrong with the loop. Thanks!!

Comment: Each time you go through your loop, you are assigning `x` to an empty data frame, overwriting the previous value. One approach would be to make `x` a list before entering the loop... but of course loops aren't very *R*-like.

Comment: 1. Don't use 'c' as a variable name. This is already a function to create vectors or lists. 2. The problem is that your first line IN the for-loop should be OUTSIDE of the for-loop. 3. Subsetting is done a lot easier in another way. (See below)

Comment: Thank you guys for answering this question! All comments are very helpful! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already there good comments and answer has been mentioned for this. Still I wanted to clarify few points which can help `OP`.

Obviously `for-loop` are very much `r-like` as loops are not very efficient in many cases. Even though if you want to fix the problem in your loop then just modify it as:

```
# Calling seed will ensure same output from function like sample. This will 
# generate consistent result in every attempt
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(rep(1:5, 10), 10)
b <- sample(rep(1:5, 10), 10)
c <- data.frame(a, b)  # good to name it df
s <- c(1,2)

# Fix for-loop
x <- data.frame() #assign x out of the for-loop
for (i in s){
  x <- rbind(x, c[which(a==i),])
}
#Result
> x
#  a b
#6 1 3
#7 2 2
#9 2 1

# R-like approach
> c[c$a %in% s,]  #use the column of 'c' dataframe directly in condition
#  a b
#6 1 3
#7 2 2
#9 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I chose this answer for both correcting my loop and giving a new way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid `for` loop and subset rows by matching the values in `s1` with `a1`.

```
set.seed(1L)
a1 <- sample(rep(1:5, 10), 10)
b1 <- sample(rep(1:5, 10), 10)
c1 <- data.frame(a1, b1)
s1 <- c(1,2)

a1 %in% s1
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

c1[ a1 %in% s1, ]
#   a1 b1
# 6  1  3
# 7  2  2
# 9  2  1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very efficient!